# .htaccess for redirect all requests to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have those rules in my .htaccess for redirect all requests to index.php. And it works. 
But i see pictures on second pages don't show.
But pictures  on main page are shown.
How i can configure those rules additional?

Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: Define base href in <head> on every page and set it to your website url <base href="http://your-web-url.com">

Comment: Do not use relative links anywhere! `href="img/some-image.jpg"` should be changed to `href="/img/some-image.jpg"`. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the .htaccess I use

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Also, do not use relative links anywhere! `href="img/some-image.jpg"` should be changed to `href="/img/some-image.jpg"`.

Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I jast add "/" to front my link.

Comment: great! Can you mark this the correct answer please? :-)